# ntpstat works but not ntpq

Tags: linux, ntp

I'm trying to configure NTP client on RHEL7.4
I'm running the "ntpstat" command and seeing that I have synchronized:

```
[root@my-machine ~]# ntpstat
synchronised to NTP server (ntp-server ip) at stratum 5
   time correct to within 1173 ms
   polling server every 64 s
```

but when I'm running the "ntpq -p" command, I'm getting an error:

```
[root@my-machine ~]# ntpq -p
localhost.ntp-server.com: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

For some reason NTP has appended a prefix of "localhost" to ntp-server hostname.

Here is my /etc/ntp.conf:

```
[root@my-machine ~]# egrep -v '^#|^[[:blank:]]*$' /etc/ntp.conf
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
server ntp-server.com prefer iburst
```

I should make the "ntpq" command working as this machine part of Cloudera cluster and cloudera-agent using the "ntpq -np" to be sure that NTP is synchronized.

Comment: my guest is that your host machine is serving NTP to your VM and you doesn't really need ntp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue.
For some strange reason it was lack of localhost lines in /etc/hosts at all.

So I have appended the lines bellow to /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Once I added such lines, the issue was solved.